# EF - Getting metadata about related entities by eager loading to avoid extra DB calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**Scenario:**

1. I have Users. Each user can be an "author" to an Article. (An article can have several collaborating "authors".)
2. I want to present a GUI interface to search for an User by name. You will be presented a list where the authors who have any articles have a link to their articles, while the ones with zero still will be presented but without the link.

**Implementation:**

1. I present a search interface for the client. They send the search string to my UserSearchForArticlesList-controller where I ask EF for all the Users that have a name that match the search query and sent this list to my View.
2. The view iterates through the list of Users. For each it checks if it has any documents that is public (Connection table for User<->Article, I know that EF can solve this without making this visible, but that's how it is now.) If the User has connections to public Articles, it creates an ActionLink, counts the public articles and presents this count by the link.

Controller (without any eager loading of needed data in View):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserSearchForArticlesList(string searchTerm)
{
    var model = myEF.Users.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.UserArticles.Any(o => o.Article.IsPublic))
        {
            <li>@Html.RouteLink(item.Name, "UserArticles", new { item.Id }) (@item.UserArticles.Count(o => o.Article.IsPublic))</li>
        }else
        {
            <li title="No public articles for this User">@item.Name</li>
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

With lazy loading the relations for the User, I get several calls for each User I present in the list. When I eager load (.Inlude(user => user.UserArticles.Articles)) I get only one call, but with way to much data then I actually need.

Is it possible that you somehow can get EF to get the matching Users and the count of the connected public Articles for that user, using only a reasonable amount of DB calls?

<del>**"Just after writing a big article about my problem"-insight:**</del>

<del>It actually just hit me when debugging and looking at the EF profiler that both the if-clause and the count in the View is resulting in a lot of single row querys to the DB. Why is this? Shouldn't EF figure out some minified SQL queries for this?</del>

**UPDATE:**

I obviously did not have enough experience of EF to make an informed question about this. One problem in my above post is that i do not enumerate the IQueryable before iterating it in the View, hence it will make a SQL request for each step. Though, the main issue is still at large.

Comment: And this is how I eager load the relations: _var model = myEF.Users.Include(user => user.UserArticles.Article).Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).OrderBy(x => x.Name)};_ , but as I said, thats way to much data then needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for disable LazyLoading.

The first way, to use property myEF.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

and the second way, to use UserArticles list without **virtual** world.

```
public class User 
{ 
    public ICollection<UserArticle> UserArticles { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I've got no problem with the disabliling of the lazy loading itself, I just include the related properties I want, but the problem is still that I in that case get way to much data then I need.